# installing new version of libtool for -- libwebsocket warmcat

Tags: linux, websocket, embedded-linux, libtool

I am installing libwebsocket  it is giving me error :---
http://git.warmcat.com/cgi-bin/cgit/libwebsockets/snapshot/libwebsockets-1.0-chrome25-firefox17.tar.gz

```
/pi/libwebsockets-1.0-chrome25-firefox17$ ./autogen.sh 
Preparing the libwebsockets build system...please wait

Found GNU Autoconf version 2.69
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = "en_US:",
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = "en_US:",
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
Found GNU Automake version 1.13
Found GNU Libtool version 1.5.26

Automatically preparing build ... Warning: autoreconf failed
Attempting to run the preparation steps individually

Preparing build ... ERROR: aclocal failed
```

At present when i run libtool --version:---

```
/home/pi$ libtool --version
ltmain.sh (GNU libtool) 1.5.26 (1.1220.2.492 2008/01/30 06:40:56)

Copyright (C) 2008  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

If i run whereis command, i get following output :----

```
/pi/libtool-2.4.2$ whereis libtool
libtool:
```

I have to install libtool version 2.4.2, to get rid of above error.
Now i have installed 2.4.2 version for libtool :---
ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/libtool/libtool-2.4.2.tar.gz

After installing 2.4.2 version of libtool, If i run whereis command, i get following output :----

```
/pi/libtool-2.4.2$ whereis libtool
libtool: /usr/local/bin/libtool
```

But if i run libtool --version:---

```
/home/pi$ libtool --version
ltmain.sh (GNU libtool) 1.5.26 (1.1220.2.492 2008/01/30 06:40:56)
```

Why libtool --version command is not showing the latest installed version of libtool 2.4.2?

Also i am getting same error for libwebsocket when i run ./autogen.sh .

Comment: what & where is this file ---  ltmain.sh  ?  It is hiding actual libtool installed ? please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the latest version (1.22) using CMake?  It's straight forward to build.

```
$ git clone git://git.libwebsockets.org/libwebsockets
$ cd libwebsockets/
```

Read README.build.  Don't know the old version of libwebsockets, but I guess it's
now more towards using CMake rather than autotools.

```
$ mkdir build && cd build
$ cmake ..  -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/usr/local
```

The last line is similar to:

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local
```

The whole thing built pretty quick and without any issue.